# Conditional calculating SUM in column using data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table, plyr

This is continue of the question [How to output duplicated rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520828/how-to-output-duplicated-rows/26520921?noredirect=1#comment41685969_26520921)

I have the table:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4
34  14  45  53 
2   8   18  17
34  14  45  20
19  78  21  48 
2   8   18  5
```

You can notice that rows 1 and 3 are very similar, except one last column. How can I calculate the sum of those values in column 3  (53+20) and remain only one of those two similar rows, but using data.table

The output should be:

```
x1  x2  x3  x4
34  14  45  73
2   8   18  22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <-paste0("x",1:3)
setDT(df)[df[, duplicated(.SD)|duplicated(.SD,fromLast=TRUE), 
                 .SDcols=nm1]][, list(x4=sum(x4)), by=list(x1,x2,x3)]
#   x1 x2 x3 x4
#1: 34 14 45 73
#2:  2  8 18 22
```

Or

```
DT <- data.table(df)
setkey(DT,x1,x2,x3)
DT[duplicated(DT)|duplicated(DT,fromLast=TRUE)][, 
                 list(x4=sum(x4)), by=list(x1,x2,x3)]

#   x1 x2 x3 x4
#1:  2  8 18 22
#2: 34 14 45 73
```

#### Update

If `-` and `''` are in the columns that are otherwise numeric, then we could you use `as.numeric` and coerce them to `NA` with a warning. For example

```
 dat <- data.frame(Col1= c(3, '', 2:5), Col2=c(4, 5, '-', 2, 6, 8),
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.numeric)
 #Warning message:
 #In lapply(dat, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
 dat
 # Col1 Col2
 #1    3    4
 #2   NA    5
 #3    2   NA
 #4    3    2
 #5    4    6
 #6    5    8
```

Or you could specify this while reading the dataset.  Using the same data saved in a file

```
read.table('fileNew.txt', sep=',',  header=TRUE, na.strings=c('', '-'))
#   Col1 Col2
#1    3    4
#2   NA    5
#3    2   NA
#4    3    2
#5    4    6
#6    5    8
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c(34L, 2L, 34L, 19L, 2L), x2 = c(14L, 8L, 
14L, 78L, 8L), x3 = c(45L, 18L, 45L, 21L, 18L), x4 = c(53L, 17L, 
20L, 48L, 5L)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Could you tell me how can I replace "-" and "" in my data set with NA? Thank you!