# find duplicated rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r

A dataframe looks like

```
A 1
A 1
A 2
B 3
B 3
B 4
C 5
C 5
C 6
```

I want it becomes:

```
A 1
A 1
B 3
B 3
C 5
C 5
```

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520828/how-to-output-duplicated-rows/26520973

Comment: Actually might be an exact dup since `dat[duplicated(dat) | duplicated(dat, fromLast=T),]` and `dat[with(dat, ave(V2,list(V1,V2),FUN=length)>1 ),]` both give the intended result using answers from that page.

Comment: you actually aren't finding the duplicated element, which would be the second occurrence of 1,3, and 5. Rather it looks like you are removing the second unique value in each group.

Comment: With base, maybe `do.call(rbind, Filter(function(x){nrow(x) > 1}, split(df, df)))`; or in dplyr, `df %>% group_by_(.dots = names(.)) %>% filter(n() > 1)`